# Convert a huge PNG picture to an interactive, zoomable map?

Tags: data-visualization, maps, web, png

I generated a 65k x 65k (4 *giga*pixels) image that is basically a visualisation of the entire IPv4 address space from one perspective:

[image: Hilbert curve of rDNS distribution in the entire Internet]

No browser is willing to load an image that big, claiming it might be a gzip-bomb. This means I'm forced to split it into tiles at different zoom levels and add a front-end for interactive browsing of the map, just like in Google Maps (but for the IP addresses).

Is there a project that would let me do it quickly? Right now I'm thinking of experimenting with [Leaflet's CRS-Simple](https://leafletjs.com), but that means I would have to figure out the alignment of the tiles, etc. to get a complete project. Is there an "all-in-one" solution that starts with a huge image and ends with a zoomable map? Bonus points if it supports Hilbert curves, or even better - IPv4 Hilbert curves, though just having an interactive map generator would be good.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`gdal2tiles`](https://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html) to generate an image pyramid that [leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) or [openlayers](http://openlayers.org) can use to display your image in a browser.

There is a fairly comprehensive [tutorial](https://digitalprojectstudio.wordpress.com/2015/07/01/adding-gdal2tiles-layer-to-leaflet-map/) or a [github project](https://github.com/commenthol/gdal2tiles-leaflet) that wraps the code for plain images like yours and generates the required html page.

Answer (score 2):

Besides gdal2tiles, you could use [vips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/). Details are in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51852934/10168903

If you want a GUI based solution, you could use [Photoshop](https://zoomable.ca/create_from_photoshop.html) or [Microsoft Image Composite Editor](https://zoomable.ca/create_from_desktop.html). You would need a plugin from [zoomable.ca](https://zoomable.ca) though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Syncfusion Essential JS2 Maps component. This will load any image/tile from the server and render it as a map. Also, it provides many user interactive features.

- Product page – https://www.syncfusion.com/javascript-ui-controls/maps
- Demo samples –
  https://ej2.syncfusion.com/demos/#/material/maps/default.html
- UG Documentation –
  https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/maps/getting-started