# Tool to create an interactive fantasy map

Tags: maps

I have an image, which is a custom map for a fantasy world, and would like to be able to create a zoomable, interactive map with that image as the base, and the ability to add markers on the map.

Something like this: https://genshin-impact-map.appsample.com/#/

I have tried [Zoomable](https://zoomable.ca/), but it is great in terms of making an interactive map, but it doesn't allow adding markers, which is the feature I need (to see information about certain points in the map). I have also read [this answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/52391/convert-a-huge-png-picture-to-an-interactive-zoomable-map), but it doesn't ask about the interactive part of the map.

I am also not talking about *generating* a map, as I already have one. I want to make it interactive, and would really like to have that image to be hosted by them as well, if possible.

Is there any such tool?

Comment: Can you code  ?  ..

Comment: Yes, but I don't like building a whole webapp just to support interaction.

Comment: Maybe you can treat it as learning a new skill, rather than a chore? Try google maps, or Leaflet wrapped around Open Street maps (which I prefer), and either use something you already know, or learn a new skill like Flutter or Angular, which can come in useful for many things (prefer Flutter). Or, let's hope that you get an answer here :-)

Comment: Hmm, we can use custom image with Google Maps?

Comment: That, I do not know, sorry. Without knowing how, I find myself certain that you could do it with Open Street Maps and Leaflet. Just look at the [Leaflet layer providers](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/). And read [Creating an Interactive World Map with Leaflet.js](https://www.techtrail.net/creating-an-interactive-map-with-leaflet-js/) and [Leaflet js fictional map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298791/leaflet-js-fictional-map), etc

Comment: Now Leaflet is an answer! You could put that as an answer =) And that SO question is exactly my question. Thanks for the links

Comment: No problems. I am using Leaflet with AngularJs and loving it. I am also looking to use it in Flutter, but while the plug ins exist with basic functionality, it is not quite as full-featured.

Comment: Answer posted, with hopefully enough info to help others who read this question in future.

Comment: If you click on the tick by the answer, that accepts it and shows others who read the question in future that it is accepted, works and answers the question, thus helping them.

Comment: Yes, I'm still waiting for other people to notice this question, though. And I am still trying to make it work first, hehe. Don't worry about the reps, I will accept it once I confirm it works for my purpose.

Comment: No problems. I saw form  your rep on this site that you are new here. I was too lazy to check your other rep, but see that you certainly know how things work on S.E ;-)  As you can see from my rep, I don't need the points; I just don't like unanswered questions :-)  Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with Open Street Maps and JavaScript and [Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/). Leaflet is easy to learn and has extensive documentation. S.O has over 4k questions with the Leaflet tag, so you know that you can get good help there (I have).

The [Leaflet layer providers](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/) may help.

And read [Creating an Interactive World Map with Leaflet.js](https://www.techtrail.net/creating-an-interactive-map-with-leaflet-js/). It draws this map, and adds markers and tooltips. It also provides full source code to study and adapt.

[image]

[image]

The S.O question [Leaflet js fictional map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37298791/leaflet-js-fictional-map) has an accepted and upvoted answer which will also help you. To save you reading it, it links to [this](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/questions-with-yes-or-no-answers.html) (which seems to be broken, but ymmv) and to [this part](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html) of the official Leaflet docuemtnation.

Comment: Ok, the combination of the first (for tileLayer) and second (for CRS.Simple) tutorial work nicely! I had to add a few more plugins for my needs, but this is the right answer! The tutorial on interactive map requires photoshop plugin for creating the tiles, but I don't have Photoshop. Fortunately I made the map myself so I could also cut the maps myself. Hopefully in the future there will be scripts to help people cut their maps without Photoshop.

Comment: I am glad to hear that you managed it. Have fun :-)